# Sub-queries in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a query in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM group_recordings WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM group_recordings GROUP BY time_span )
```

there is a sub-query in "IN" operator, I want to convert this query in laravel eloquent, I have GroupRecording Model. Anyone help me with that

Answer (score 0):

I think the Laravel style of such query will be,

```
GroupRecording::whereIn('id', function($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
                ->from('group_recordings')
                ->groupBy('time_span');
            })
            ->where('time_span', '>', $recording->time_span)
            ->get();
```